# How can we remove blank line without strip-space and indent XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying remove blank lines without stripping spaces and indentation, because my requirement is indented XML. Can anyone help me, please?

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export>
<bio id="b0001">

<p>Maciej</p>
</bio>
<funding-group>

<award-group>
<funding-source>
<named-content content-type="funder-name">Narodowe</named-content>
<named-content content-type="funderidentifier">501100004281</named-content>
</funding-source>
<award-id>/19/B/HS4/</award-id>
<award-id>3</award-id>
</award-group>
</funding-group>
</Export>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export>
<bio id="b0001">
<p>Maciej</p>
</bio>
<funding-group>
<award-group>
<funding-source>
<named-content content-type="funder-name">Narodowe Centrum Nauki</named-content>
<named-content content-type="funderidentifier">10.13039/501100004281</named-content>
</funding-source>
<award-id>/19/B/HS4/</award-id>
<award-id>3</award-id>
</award-group>
</funding-group>
</Export>
```

**XSLT** I have tried this xsl but it's not worked properly if i have run this xsl then generate XML single line.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;&#xD;', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "I am trying" OK, and what did you try so far? Include it in your question, and explain why it didn't work for your needs.

Comment: @ underscore_d Thanks for the response because my requirement is only remove blank line if i have used `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and **indent="yes"** then remove blank line but all Element showing the indent.